# XML parent node search using classic ASP

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I've got the task of working on a Classic ASP site and need to parse out the following information in a loop.

XML :

```
<rows>
    <row id='3'>
        <cell>3-1</cell>
        <cell>3-2</cell>
        <cell>3-3</cell>
        <cell>3-4</cell>
        <row id='2'>
            <cell>2-1</cell>
            <cell>2-2</cell>
            <cell>2-3</cell>
            <cell></cell>
        </row>
        <row id='A'>
            <cell>A-1</cell>
            <cell>A-2</cell>
            <cell>A-3</cell>
            <cell>A-4</cell>
        </row>
    </row>
    <row id='7'>
        <cell>ABC</cell>
        <cell>3</cell>
        <cell>0</cell>
        <cell></cell>
    </row>
    <row id='B'>
        <cell>B-1</cell>
        <cell>B-2</cell>
        <cell>B-3</cell>
        <cell>B-4</cell>
        <row id='B-1'>
            <cell>B-1-1</cell>
            <cell>B-2-2</cell>
            <cell>B-3-3</cell>
            <cell>B-4-4</cell>
            <row id='B-1-1'>
                <cell>B-1-1</cell>
                <cell>B-2-2</cell>
                <cell>B-3-3</cell>
                <cell>B-4-4</cell>
            </row>
        </row>
    </row>
</rows>
```

Wanted Result:

```
PID:  / ID : 3 / 3-1/3-2/3-3/3-4/
PID:  3/ ID : 2 / 2-1/2-2/2-3//
PID:  3/ ID : A / A-1/A-2/A-3/A-4/
PID:  / ID : 7 / ABC/3/0//
PID:  / ID : B / B-1/B-2/B-3/B-4/
PID:  B/ ID : B-1 / B-1-1/B-2-2/B-3-3/B-4-4/
PID:  B-1/ ID : B-1-1 / B-1-1/B-2-2/B-3-3/B-4-4/
```

Classic ASP Code :

```
Set Nodes = oDOM.getElementsByTagName("row")

For each Subnodes in Nodes

    Response.Write("PID : " + ?????? + " / ")
    Response.Write("ID : " + CStr(SubNodes.getElementsByTagName("cell")(0).parentNode.Attributes(0).Text) + " / ")

    Response.Write(SubNodes.getElementsByTagName("cell")(0).Text + "/")
    Response.Write(SubNodes.getElementsByTagName("cell")(1).Text + "/")
    Response.Write(SubNodes.getElementsByTagName("cell")(2).Text + "/")
    Response.Write(SubNodes.getElementsByTagName("cell")(3).Text + "/")
    Response.WRite("<br>")
Next
```

I hope to get the parent id but Nodes.parentNode is not working. How can I get the parents id? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `Subnodes` already contains the "row" you want, so `SubNodes.Attributes(0).Text`should yield the row ID.

I would also advise to execute `SubNodes.getElementsByTagName("cell")` only once (per row obviously) and store the result in a variable, which you can then access as an array, like so:

```
set cells = SubNodes.getElementsByTagName("cell")

Response.Write(cells(0).Text + "/")
Response.Write(cells(1).Text + "/")
Response.Write(cells(2).Text + "/")
Response.Write(cells(3).Text + "/")
```

Otherwise you are searching for all sub-cells in the DOM for each item you are using.